# understanding the definition of Q lies over p

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

If $A \subset B$ is an extension of Dedekind domains and $p \in A$ is a prime ideal  , does $Q_i$ lie over $p$ if $p\cdot B=Q_1^{e_1}\cdot...\cdot Q_r^{e_r}$ for $Q_i\subset B $ prime ideals ?

Comment: Yes if $e_i > 0$. Also this happens if and only if  $Q_i \cap A = p$. Take for example $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ over $\mathbb{Z}$. Then $5 \mathbb{Z}[i] = (2+i)(2-i)$ and so both $(2+i)$ and $(2-i)$ lie over $5$.

Comment: Thanks for your help . Can you also say that  the prime ideals $(2+i)$ and $(2-i)$ lie over $\sqrt{5}$ ?

Comment: I am sorry but that statement does not make any sense. $\sqrt{5}$ is not an integer. $p$ has to be an element of $A$. I think you should read the definitions again carefully. I would suggest Milne's online lecture notes.

Comment: if you consider $K=\mathbb{Q(\sqrt{5}})$ . Can you say that a prime $a$ over $5$ lies also over $\sqrt{5}$ .?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that, in Dedekind domains, every nonzero prime is maximal. As
$$p ⊆ pB = Q_1^{e_1}·…·Q_r^{e_r} ⊆ Q_i,$$ we have $p ⊆ Q_i ∩ A$ for $i = 1, …, r$. As $p$ is maximal, $p = Q_i ∩ A$.